# Button position on widget

Tags: flutter

I am trying to put a button on the edge on a widget in centre , but I don't know what to use ... alignment , positioned? padding?Or should I move the position of the button somehow in the first container? can you help me with my code

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flappy_search_bar/flappy_search_bar.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'UserProfiles.dart';
import 'viewProfiles.dart';

class CustomerPosts extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  CustomerPostsState createState() => CustomerPostsState();
}

class CustomerPostsState extends State<CustomerPosts> {
  TextEditingController textEditingController = TextEditingController();
  final database = Firestore.instance;
  String searchString;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Container(child: Column(children: <Widget>[TopText()])));
  }
}

class TopText extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 60, left: 20, right: 20),
        child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    "Hey there,\n customers are needing you ",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontFamily: 'Helvetica',
                        fontSize: 24),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 15),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
                    child: Container(
                      width: 360,
                      height: 200,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                            topLeft: Radius.circular(60),
                            topRight: Radius.circular(60),
                            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(60),
                            bottomRight: Radius.circular(60)),
                        boxShadow: [
                          BoxShadow(
                            color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                            spreadRadius: 5,
                            blurRadius: 7,
                            offset: Offset(0, 3),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: -5),
                      child: RaisedButton(
                          onPressed: () {},
                          child: Text(
                            "POST",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                          ),
                          color: Colors.blueAccent),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              )
            ]));
  }
}
```

This is what I have ,[image I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/js58U.png) and this is what I try to get:[image I try to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91gsm.png)

Comment: Use stack widget for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Would recommend to use Stack and use the position to position the RaisedButton to the bottom of the screen.

```
class CustomerPosts extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  CustomerPostsState createState() => CustomerPostsState();
}

class CustomerPostsState extends State<CustomerPosts> {
  TextEditingController textEditingController = TextEditingController();
  //final database = Firestore.instance;
  String searchString;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Container(child: Column(children: <Widget>[TopText()])));
  }
}

class TopText extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 60, left: 20, right: 20),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                "Hey there,\n customers are needing you ",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontFamily: 'Helvetica',
                    fontSize: 24),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 15),
              Stack(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: 200,
                    width: 360,
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      vertical: 30.0,
                    ),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          topLeft: Radius.circular(60),
                          topRight: Radius.circular(60),
                          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(60),
                          bottomRight: Radius.circular(60)),
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                          spreadRadius: 5,
                          blurRadius: 7,
                          offset: Offset(0, 3),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    bottom: 0,
                    child: RaisedButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        child: Text(
                          "POST",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                        ),
                        color: Colors.blueAccent),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is what it looks like:
[image]